# afterScriptsLoaded event is not working when switching tabs in community

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a controller action that I want to execute on "**afterScriptsLoaded**" event and its working fine when I run Lightning application directly but when I create Community Builder page for the lightning component and show that page as Tab on Community.
Now when I click Tab to open lightning component this time "**afterScriptsLoaded**" event is not working and if I refresh the complete page then it works.

Is there any work around for the issue?

Comment: `afterScriptsLoaded` event probably only called when the page load first time. Switching tab is a javascript action and doesn't reload scripts again. Just a guess.

Comment: is there any workround to fire the function ro make sure a js function is fired after the tab is switched?